# React-native debug build crash on start: Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.SystraceRequestListener

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, react-native-tools

I am trying to create a debug build of my app in react-native. It worked previously and the problem started after I used react-native-tools extension package for VSCode text editor and attached its debugger for debugging. The error doesn't occur when I create a release build. I have removed the extension, removed my project node_modules folder and reinstalled.

The error is as follows:

```
08-30 13:15:42.896 6228-6491/? E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-30 13:15:42.957 25112-25112/? E/art: Failed to send JDWP packet APNM to debugger (-1 of 51): Broken pipe
08-30 13:15:42.961 25112-25118/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-30 13:15:43.052 25112-25138/? E/Theme: Different package name.com.namahapp,com.google.android.gms
08-30 13:15:43.110 25112-25151/? E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-30 13:15:43.155 18392-18909/? E/Theme: Different package name.com.facebook.katana,com.google.android.gms
08-30 13:15:43.246 18666-22557/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
08-30 13:15:43.332 25112-25165/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
                                                Process: com.namahapp, PID: 25112
                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.SystraceRequestListener
                                                    at com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.getDefaultConfigBuilder(FrescoModule.java:149)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.getDefaultConfig(FrescoModule.java:138)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.initialize(FrescoModule.java:101)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize(ModuleHolder.java:198)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable(ModuleHolder.java:86)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized(NativeModuleRegistry.java:123)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:387)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The react-native version is 0.55.4. 
My package.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "NamahApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.3.1",
        "react-native": "0.55.4",
        "react-native-check-app-install": "0.0.4",
        "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
        "react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.6.0",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
        "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
        "react-native-share": "^1.0.27",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.2",
        "react-native-sound": "^0.10.9",
        "react-native-svg": "^6.5.0",
        "react-navigation": "^2.0.1",
        "socketcluster-client": "^13.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "jest": "22.4.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./app/assets/fonts/"
        ]
    }
}
```

I can't make out what the error is and how to address it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 31/08/2018**

I opened the file with the error and found that the file is available in two places:

- `C:\Users\Nikhil\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-native\0.12.0\8a53a72920675231a5d11880ae3cacb9ab91b93c\react-native-0.12.0-sources.jar!\com\facebook\react\modules\fresco\FrescoModule.java` in Users folder (Windows).
- `G:\path\to\project\node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.55.0\react-native-0.55.0-sources.jar!\com\facebook\react\modules\fresco\FrescoModule.java`

Out of those the file in `Users` folder does not have the `SystraceRequestListener.java` file.

Also, the react-native version in the path is 0.12.0. How is this getting set?? How do I change this?? I guess it should have been 0.55.4 i.e. current react-native version used in the project.

Where should I do the changes?? In Project?? or in Android studio base settings??

Please help...

**Update-2 31/08/18**

Removed the .gradle/cache file from `Users` folder but the error still persists.

Now the error is definitely in the .gradle folder in the project.

Now need to determine why the error occurs even as the `SystraceRequestListener.java` exists in the same folder as the file in which the error occurs i.e. `FrescoModule.java`.

**Update 03/09/18 (3rd Sept)**

I reinstalled and configured all the npm packages used in the project to find when the build gets the above error, and I found that the issue occurs when I install react-native-firebase. Will update if I find some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was emerging from the react-native-firebase package.

Updating the react-native-firebase package to the latest version resolved my problem.